# MongoDB Schema for interview time slot availability

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm building a website where admins can create interviews by selecting participants,
interview start time and end time. I have divided the participants into two groups(collections) - Applicants and Team_Members.
I tried creating a 3rd collection called Interviews to keep track of the start and end times for each interview but I don't think that there's a need for a 3rd collection now.
So far, these are the schemas I have come up with -

```js
const applicantSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  interviews: [
    {
      start_time: String,
      end_time: String,
    },
  ],
});
```

```js
const interviewerSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: "download.png",
  },
  interviews: [{
    start_time: String,
    end_time: String,
  }, ],
});
```

How should I update the interviews property once each new interview is booked? And am I going in the right direction in terms of forming the schemas for the problem required?

Comment: Why are you building 2 separate schemas for interviews?

Comment: @FahadSubzwari Because I want to choose from interviewers and interviewees separately.

Comment: do you have your interviews records in any other collection like users or any other collection?

Comment: @FahadSubzwari No I don't, I just have 2 collections for now. I don't know if making a third one for interview slots would be better or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same schema for both. Just add `interviewee: { type: boolean, required: true }` and add that criteria when you do a search.
for the interviews start and end times, change the values to Date, like that you will be able to search them and find dates `> $gt` or `< $st` to make sure you don't double book a time slot. For marking booked, simply add another value called `booked: { type: boolean, default: false'

```js
const interviewSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  interviewee: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  interviews: [
    {
      start_time: {
        type: Date, 
        default: new Date()
      },
      end_time:  {
        type: Date, 
        default: new Date()
      },
      booked: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false
      }
    },
  ],
});
```